# Suspend broken on HP X360 310 G2

Tags: suspend, hp, acpi

Another one of those "suspend doesn't work" posts... :o(

I use Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic (Kernel 5.4.0.54-generic x86_64) on my HP X360 310 G2 convertible laptop and suspend doesn't work. I've googled for hours and hours to no avail.

- "Suspend when laptop lid is closed" is set to "ON" in Gnome Tweak tool.
- "When the power button is pressed" is set to "Suspend" in Settings.
- When suspend is initiated, the system is apparently suspended (?) for 2-3 seconds (network adapter light goes out), and then tries to wake up (I can see the UEFI "HP" logo for a brief moment) and fails (console 1 goes from `/dev/sda4: clean` all the way to `Started RealTimeKit Scheduling Policy Service` or sometimes to `Started Samba SMB Daemon` and then stops, no GUI.
- At this point, I can log in at the other consoles.
- When pressing the power button or issuing `systemctl suspend` or `systemctl suspend -i` at the console, the network adapter is apparently suspended (light goes out) for 2-3 seconds before coming back again. The screen stays on and doesn't change.

Some more info:

- ACPI supports S0 S3 S4 S5.
- `/sys/power/mem_sleep` is `s2idle [deep]`.
- Wake on LAN is disabled for the network interface.
- `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` has `suspend` for all the relevant entries set and uncommented.
- Plugging out the USB-C hub and the LAN cable (so nothing is left plugged in) don't help.
- `dmesg` doesn't tell much about the suspend attempt other than:

  - `systemd-logind: hybernation is restricted`... (I'm not trying to hybernate but to suspend, do I?)
  - Network adapter `Link is Down`
  - Network adapter `Link is Up` (immediately after the other)

Thanks for any tips, and I'll be happy to try possible solutions (albeit swapping the kernel is something
I'd prefer to avoid).